# How to get local users username from Web2Py?

Tags: python, apache, wsgi, web2py

I am working on a web2py app which I would like to be able to use some of the user's local variables to customize things a bit, specifically I am trying to get the user's domain and username.. I know that this is possible running on an Apache using the module "mod_auth_sspi".

Is this possible on a Rocket WSGI 1.2.6 server? Or has anybody tried doing this on a web2py app before? Is there a python module that could do this?

Comment: Do you mean Apache instead of Ajax?

Comment: Yes sorry, I'll change that now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ended up moving the web2py app over to an Apache server. If somebody doesn't know how to do this then you can find all of the documentation here:

http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/13

After that I installed the mod_auth_sspi module in order to get instructions. The x86 version of the module can be downloaded from here:

http://goo.gl/syzjuk

It will require an x86 installation of Apache though. After it is downloaded:

1. Unzip the file
2. Drag mod_auth_sspi.so from the bin folder into wherever you modules folder
   for your Apache installation is.
3. Add `LoadModule sspi_auth_module modules/mod_auth_sspi.so` to your httpd.conf file as 
   well as any sspi settings you need to whichever location you need to apply security to.

I did have some issues with authentication on some browsers, but I did find solutions which you can find here:

[How can you store a log in using mod_auth_sspi on Apache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18238549/how-can-you-store-a-log-in-using-mod-auth-sspi-on-apache)